# Listview, remove duplicates using LINQ and based in subitem comparing

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, visual-studio, listview

I would like to remove duplicates from a `ListViewItemCollection` based on a subitem index.

The approach is important to be using `LINQ`.

This is what I was trying with no luck:

```
Private Function RemoveListViewDuplicates(ByVal Items As ListView.ListViewItemCollection,
                                          ByVal CompareColumn As Integer) As ListView.ListViewItemCollection

    Dim Deduplicated =
        (From Item As ListViewItem In Items
         Group By Item.SubItems(CompareColumn).Text Into Distinct()) '.ToArray
    ' At this point the good thing is that the '.Distinct' grouped member of the 
    ' resulting 'Deduplicated' object contains only the non-duplicated ListviewItems
    ' but, I can't find the way to return that single member '.Distinct' as a 'ListView.ListViewItemCollection'
    ' instead of returning both '.Text' and '.Distinct' members.
    '
    ' I just want to return the 'Items' object that I pass to the function but without duplicates,
    ' and in the same return-type of the object that I've passed to this function 
    ' (ListView.ListViewItemCollection) as you can understand.

    Return Deduplicated

End Function
```

And then I should can do this:

```
    Dim items As ListView.ListViewItemCollection =
        RemoveListViewDuplicates(ListView1.Items, 0)

    For Each Item As ListViewItem In items
        MsgBox(Item.Text)
    Next Item
```

> UPDATE

I'm trying the solution answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603036/removing-duplicate-items-from-a-multicolumn-listview) but with a little modifications to preserve 1 duplicated item on the collection, the problem that I have is that this works directlly on the ListView control tehn is not what I wanted, I want to work on an object that stores the current items of a listview control but without affecting directlly on the control when removing duplicates...

This is the method:

```
Private Function RemoveListViewDuplicates(ByVal Items As ListView.ListViewItemCollection,
                                          ByVal SubitemCompare As Integer) As ListView.ListViewItemCollection

    Dim Duplicates As ListViewItem() =
        Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem)().
        GroupBy(Function(Item As ListViewItem) Item.SubItems(SubitemCompare).Text).
        Where(Function(g As IGrouping(Of String, ListViewItem)) g.Count <> 1).
        SelectMany(Function(g As IGrouping(Of String, ListViewItem)) g).
        Skip(1).
        ToArray()

    ' This removes the items from the listview control, directlly
    For Each Item As ListViewItem In Duplicates
        Items.Remove(Item)
    Next Item

    Return Items

End Function
```

Desired usage:

```
    Dim DuplicatedItems As ListView.ListViewItemCollection =
        New ListView.ListViewItemCollection(ListView1)

    Dim DeDuplicatedItems As ListView.ListViewItemCollection =
        RemoveListViewDuplicates(DuplicatedItems, 0)

    ' I add the Items without duplicates on another Listview, 
    ' preserving the duplicates on the original Listview1 control.
    ListView2.Items.AddRange(DeDuplicatedItems)
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3603036/1070452 I was going to mention a Comparer which is used there. Also, I am curious why it is 'important' to use LINQ.

Comment: @Plutonix yes I've seen it before create my question but to be honest I didn't read the interesting part at the end of the answer. I'm trying to use that solution but is giving me a little problem, maybe is easy to solve for you, please if you can read my updated question. PS: I love LINQ syntax 'cause it's simplify clausules, I know it's more efficient a For loop but I would like to replace the For usage in several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 fundamental problems in your approach.  First, ListViewItems are **objects**.  When they are removed from the ListViewItemCollection, 2 properties change: the Index (goes to 0) and the `ListView` (owner) property becomes `Nothing`.  So when you delete a ListViewItem in Collection2, it **also** deletes from the master/original collection because **they are the same LVI object**.

The other SO answer linked to (and copied above) is not an appropriate starting point because that one **does** want to delete from the source where you do not.   **Solution:**  If you want 2 collections with different LVI items in them (1==w/dupes; 2==no dupes), you have to clone items - either all the items in the first collection to start with, or clone the Dupes for the DupesCollection.  I dont know how you would do that other than in a loop (ie via LINQ).

If you clone the entire collection at the start, you should be able to proceed down the LINQ path as you wish, just make sure you are working on the cloned collection.  This seems *expensive* though, just to be able to use LINQ (the tail is wagging the dog).

Secondly, a `ListViewItemCollection` requires a LV owner.  When you create the other collection you are assigning it to a specific LV:

```
Dim DuplicatedItems As ListView.ListViewItemCollection =
    New ListView.ListViewItemCollection(ListView1)
```

That the new collection cannot be reassigned to a different LV (it seems like you want to display the Dupes in a different LV).  You cant change the owner and cannot replace `Items` directly.  You should be able to assign it to the desired destination LV at the outset, but **will** have to clone the items.  Otherwise, the only way to move the Dupe Items collection to LV2 is in a loop.

I am not sure what happens with 2 LVI Collections assigned to a single LV, but it seems expensive to make a new collection when all you really need are the Duplicate Indices:

```
   ' get a list of indices comparing the Text for SubItem(index)
    Public Function DuplicateItemIndices(index As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
        Dim lvDupes As New List(Of Integer)

        If Items.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing
        If Items(0).SubItems.Count < index Then Return Nothing

        Dim ndx As Integer

        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In Items
            ' already caught, keep going
            If lvDupes.Contains(lvi.Index) Then Continue For

            ndx = FindDupeItem(lvi, index)
            ' not sure the second condition can happen here
            If ndx > 0 AndAlso lvDupes.Contains(ndx) = False Then
                lvDupes.Add(ndx)
            End If
        Next

        Return lvDupes

    End Function

    ' returns an index for an item matching this one
    Private Function FindDupeItem(lvi As ListViewItem, 
                                  index As Integer) As Integer

        For Each lvx As ListViewItem In Items
            If lvx Is lvi Then Continue For

            If lvx.SubItems(index).Text = lvi.SubItems(index).Text Then
                Return lvx.Index
            End If
        Next
        ' signal for no match
        Return -1

    End Function
```

For what I understand your purposes to be, use the returned `List(of DuplicateItemIndices)` to **clone** items in the master list and stash in the DuplicatesLV.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the below example:

```
Dim StringList As List(Of String) = ...
StringList = StringList.Distinct().ToList()
```

***UPDATE***

Give the below a try.  Keep in mind that I'm used to writing C#, so I may have left a bit of C#.

```
Option Infer On
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module CountAtLeastExtension

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function CountAtLeast(Of T)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal minimumCount As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim count = 0
        For Each item In source
             count += 1
            If count >= minimumCount Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next

        Return False
    End Function

End Module

Private Shared Sub RemoveListViewDuplicates(ByVal listView As ListView)

    Dim duplicates = listView.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem.SubItems)() _
        .GroupBy(Function(item) item.Text) _
        .Where(Function(g) g.CountAtLeast(2)) _
        .SelectMany(Function(g) g)

    For Each duplicate As ListViewItem In duplicates
        listView.SubItems.RemoveByKey(duplicate.Name)
    Next

End Sub

Private Shared Sub RemoveDuplicateListViewItems(ByVal ListView As ListView.SubItems)

    Dim uniqueItems = New HashSet(Of ListViewItem)

    For Each item As String In ListView

        If !uniqueItems.Add(ListView.Items) Then
            ListView.SubItems.RemoveAt(item)
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but please don't miss some important things I've mentioned: The items has subitems and I just want to compare by one of those subitems then a list of string don't help me.

Comment: Also I need to simplify things to let the function do all the needed type conversions (if needed) to at the end return a `ListViewItemCollectionv` because I'm passing `ListViewItemCollectionv` on the function parameter then I don't want to mess conversions such as returning an `ListviewItem()` array or something else that isn't the same return datatype... as I mentiones here: I just want to return the object that I pass to the function but without duplicates, and in the same return-type of the object that I've passed to this function (I mean as a 'ListViewItemCollection'). thanks again.

Comment: I updated my response.  Again, please keep in mind that I'm used to writing C#, so some things may be off.  But it should at least give you the idea of what needs to happen.